# Push notifications adhoc and development for Worklight

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, ibm-mobilefirst

Does Worklight support usage of two push certificates for the same project ?

I need to test my project in both developement and production mode, so I need to put two .p12 files.

Worklight docs say that we need to name the certificate "apns-certificate-sandbox.p12", and put it on a specific folder, but what if I want to use non sandbox certificate too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place the two certificates in the project.
When testing for development, place the development certificate and when testing for production replace the certificate with the production certificate.

For development use:
apns-certificate-sandbox.p12

For production use: 
apns-certificate-production.12

Worklight will detect this and choose the correct APNS servers to use.

Comment: and Worklight will detect if it is a sandbox or production certificate, and choose the right APNS server between sandbox and not sandbox?
   The non sandbox certificate, can it be named apns-certificate-production.p12 ?

Comment: I have edited my answer above with additions based on your comment.